# Launch Google maps app from iPhone application.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps, uiapplication

I'm trying to launch google maps from my iPhone application.

The launching part works fine but since the iPhone 3.1 update (i think it was around this time) I get a zoomed out map of the US and Canada rather than zoomed in on my current location.  Everything worked fine originally but sometime around the update things stopped working correctly.

Here is the string I've been using.  This works on my partners phone with iOS 3.0 and our iPod with iOS 2.2.1 but on my phone with iOS 3.1 shows a zoomed out map of Canada and the US.

```
  NSString *name = @"clothing";
NSString *latlong = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitudeString, longitudeString];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@&mrt=yp&ll=%@",
                      [name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                      [latlong stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];    
[latlong release];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in your latitudeString and longitudeString?  Can't tell from the code shown.  Also, the latlong variable is not needed, and I don't think you need the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding on the latlong string, it should be just a floating point number.

Comment: Below is the last string that I tried.
NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=clothes&ll=45.505,-122.63&radius=30&z=8"];

I've also tried the following strings.
NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=liquor&z=13&sll=30.290525,-97.745706"];

NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=liquor&ll=45.505,-122.63&mrt=yp&z=13"];

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code I use in [one of my apps](http://nextsprinter.mggm.net/) and it works fine with 3.1.  The parameters for Google maps are [documented here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters#Location).

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D stationLocation = ...

NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]
     initWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&dirflg=d",
        curLocation.latitude,
        curLocation.longitude,
        stationLocation.latitude,
        stationLocation.longitude];

NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
[urlString release];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:aURL];
```

Comment: This doesn't give me what I need. Looks like this is used to give directions from one location to another. I'm looking for a search term around a given latitude and longitude.

I noticed something funny. Using the following URL in a web browser gives me a zoomed in map of my location & search results but when I use the same URL in my iPhone app I get a zoomed out map of the US and Canada with 10 search results.

 NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=clothes&ll=45.505,-122.63"];
 [urlString release];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:aURL];

Any ideas?

Comment: I'll bet google maps is zooming out in order to show all the search results. It looks like you can use &z= to set the map zoom level and &radius= to set the search radius. Like this:  http://maps.google.com/maps?q=clothes&ll=45.505,-122.63&radius=30&z=8

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either.  It seems like this is a 3.1 vs 3.0 problem because it works fine on my partners phone with 3.0.