# Xcode GPS navigation between 2 points

Tags: iphone, gps, xcode5

Does anyone know of a good tutorial on how to use GPS (Google maps) to navigate between 2 points in an iPhone app? I have searched for the last few hours and can only find tutorials on pinpointing current location.

What I need to do is show current position on map, and then navigation to a set destination on map. So e.g. you are at point A - navigate to point Z

What I want to do is just have a button in the app that the user clicks. Once clicked, Google Maps app open and from here Google can do the rest. I don't need the map to be displayed in my app at all.

Comment: This answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1564115/1693173) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13896151/1693173) sounds like what you want.

Comment: Thanks progrmr. Those were indeed exactly what I was looking for

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK 6 Launching maps with voice navigation directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893093/iphone-sdk-6-launching-maps-with-voice-navigation-directions)