# Google map application is not opening. Opens unrelated app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am expected to open google map direction app if it is there else i want open it in safari browser. But i am seeing unexpected behaviour that is .. instead of opening google map it is opening my other app which is installed in my device.

code i used .

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
    NSString *urlSring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",[IDUserDetails getUserCurrentLocation].latitude,[IDUserDetails getUserCurrentLocation].longitude,
                          deedModelShared.deedModel.deedCoordinate.latitude, deedModelShared.deedModel.deedCoordinate.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlSring] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

    }];

} else {
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",
                     [IDUserDetails getUserCurrentLocation].latitude,[IDUserDetails getUserCurrentLocation].longitude,
                     deedModelShared.deedModel.deedCoordinate.latitude, deedModelShared.deedModel.deedCoordinate.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

    }];
}
```

url scheme

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1564115/4831524

Comment: Have you check this new update to check app installed or not : `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
   [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemapsurl://"]];`

Comment: CodeChanger : Thanks it is woking

Comment: But usage of  "comgooglemapsurl"  is some thing related to desktop  refer this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme